# Serializing and de-serializing an associative array in bash using jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have some bash code that serializes and de-serializes a single dimensional associative array in bash using jq. It does what I want for now, but I have two issues.

The first issue is, this code feels really klunky. Especially the serialization part. Is there a better way to do this? Either with jq or some other way?

The second issue is, I can deserialize nested data (.e.g, with `{"data":{...}}`) but I can't figure out how to wrap the output in the same nested structure. How can I recreate the original structure?

Edit: Clarification. What I want to be able to do is, with the commented json, `json='{"data": {"one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3"}}'` in the example code and have the final result of 
`json='{"data": {"four": "4", "one": "100", "two": "2"}}` dumped.

I can read in the 'data' structure and assign the key/values correctly, but I'm not having any luck in figuring out how to embed the `{"four": ...}` construct into the `"data":  {...}` object.

Edit 2: The answer to my second issue, in combination with peak's answer is the following:

```
for key in "${!aaname[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n%s\n' "$key" "${aaname[$key]}"
done | jq -SRn '.data = ([inputs | {(.): input}] | add)'
```

The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#json='{"data": {"one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3"}}'
json='{"one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3"}'

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# De-serialize data

declare -A aaname

while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  aaname["$key"]="$value"
done < <(echo "$json" | jq -r '. | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value ')
#done < <(echo "$json" | jq -r '.data | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value ')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Manipulate data

# Change existing value ...
aaname['one']='100'

# Add element ...
aaname['four']='4'

# Remove element ...
unset aaname['three']

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Serialize data

# Why can't I use ${#aaname[@]} in ((...))?
total="${#aaname[@]}"
count=0

{
  printf '['
  for key in "${!aaname[@]}"; do
    printf '{"key": "%s", "value": "%s"}' "$key" "${aaname[$key]}"
    ((++count < total)) && printf ','
  done
  printf ']'
#}
#} | jq -S ' . | "data{" + from_entries + "}"'
} | jq -S ' . | from_entries'

# gives
#
#{
#  "four": "4",
#  "one": "100",
#  "two": "2"
#}
```

Comment: I don't think your code works for the nested JSON structure provided in the question

Comment: The commented code works as-is when de-serializing the data, but it doesn't work when serializing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be less klunky, and perhaps a bit more robust, if instead of:

```
jq -r '. | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value ')
```

you had:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)"'
```

And similarly you could replace the `for` loop used to create the JSON object with something like:

```
for key in "${!aaname[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\n" "$key"
    printf "%s\n" "${aaname[$key]}"
done | jq -Rn '[inputs | { (.): input}] | add'
```

Regarding the second issue, I'm afraid your question isn't so clear to me.
What format are you expecting for the non-JSON representation?
How generic a serialization/deserialization solution are you expecting?
In this connection, you might like to look at the output of `jq --stream . <<< "$json"`
for various JSON texts.

Comment: Thank you. Those two bits of code definitely look much less klunky. Added a clarification to my second issue.

Comment: One `printf` is sufficient: `printf %s\\n "$key" "${aaname[$key]}"`. You could even replace the loop with `(( ${#aaname[@]} )) && paste -d\\n <(printf %s\\n "${!aaname[@]}") <(printf %s\\n "${aaname[@]}")` **if `${!...[@]}` and `${...[@]}` always expand in the same order**. I have not found any guarantees so far, but from my experiments in bash 5.0 it seems that the order is the same for both.

Comment: I've noticed that too. However, depending on a specific order in an associative array--especially when the docs do not explicitly state order is maintained--has caught me up at the worst possible moments in the past. Also, in this particular case, it doesn't matter because I'm using the '-S' option for jq because it sorts the keys.